# Desktop environment agnostic method for prompting the user for a password?

Tags: application-development, sudo, gui, desktop-environments

In Gnome, there is `gksudo`.

In KDE, there is `kdesudo`.

Is there a command that can be run on any desktop environment that will prompt the user for the root password and then run a command?

Comment: See also: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications. If you find anything, consider submitting the information to the Freedesktop guys, since it will be generally useful.

Answer (score 2):

The [manpage for the `zenity` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/zenity) contains the following description:

> zenity  is a program that will display GTK+ dialogs, and return (either in the return code, or on standard output) the users input.

As far as I can tell (and my testing backs this up), this will work in both the Gnome and KDE desktop environments. For example:

```
zenity --password | sudo -S nautilus
```

...will prompt you for your root password and then launch Nautilus.

Comment: Wasn't there some reason you were supposed to run graphical programs using `gksu`/`kdesudo` rather than `sudo` though? Something about setting up the proper environment.

Comment: Oh. I see you're discussing it [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7608650#7608650).